# Shorten top 3 packagenames only using logback

Tags: java, logback

I know using `%logger{n}` i can get output similar to this:

```
a.b.cpackage.mypackage.MyClass - message1
a.b.c.mypackage.MyOtherClass - message2
a.b.c.m.MyVeryVeryLongClassName - message3
```

But I would like to always shorten top 3 package names, but never 4th or below

```
a.b.c.mypackage.MyClass - message1
a.b.c.mypackage.MyOtherClass - message2
a.b.c.mypackage.MyVeryVeryLongClassName - message3
```

Can this be achieved in `logback.xml`?

Logger is created using:

```
Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
```

Comment: Seems unreachable by virtue of its PatternLayout, maybe you could draw on its MDC feature,https://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html